# What is the math for finding the coordinates of top vertex of equilateral triangle in a koch curve

Tags: opengl, graphics

1. I have a OpenGL program for creating the Koch curve but I am unable to figure out the formula for finding the coordinates of the equilateral triangle.
2. Please help me understand the 2-3 lines of code comments in the following code.
3. If there is any other simple way for finding the coordinates then please do guide me.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<math.h>
#include<GL/glut.h>
#define SIN 0.866
#define COS 0.5

int n;
int X1=0,X2=550,Y1=200,Y2=200;

void Koch(int X1, int Y1, int X2, int Y2,int m)
{
    int xx,yy,x[5],y[5],lx,ly;
    lx=(X2-X1)/3;
    ly=(Y2-Y1)/3; 
    x[0]=X1;
    y[0]=Y1;
    x[4]=X2;
    y[4]=Y2;
    x[1]=x[0]+lx;
    y[1]=y[0]+ly;
    x[3]=x[0]+2*lx;
    y[3]=y[0]+2*ly;
    xx=x[3]-x[1];
    yy=y[3]-y[1];
    x[2]=xx*(0.5) + yy*(SIN);    // What does this line mean
    y[2]=-xx*(SIN)+yy*(0.5);
    x[2]=x[2]+x[1];
    y[2]=y[2]+y[1];

    if(m>0)
    {
        Koch(x[0],y[0],x[1],y[1],m-1);
        Koch(x[1],y[1],x[2],y[2],m-1);
        Koch(x[2],y[2],x[3],y[3],m-1);
        Koch(x[3],y[3],x[4],y[4],m-1); 
    }       
    else
    {
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2d(x[0],(y[0]));
        glVertex2d(x[1],(y[1]));
        glEnd();
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2d(x[1],(y[1]));
        glVertex2d(x[2],(y[2]));
        glEnd();            
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2d(x[2],(y[2]));
        glVertex2d(x[3],(y[3]));
        glEnd();            
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2d(x[3],(y[3]));
        glVertex2d(x[4],(y[4]));
        glEnd();            
    }
}

void MyDisplay()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    Koch(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,2);
    glFlush();
}

void MyInit()
{
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0 , 640 , 480 , 0);
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutCreateWindow("Koch Curve");
    MyInit();
    glutDisplayFunc(MyDisplay);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SIN is approximately equal to math's sin function sin(60). COS is equal to math's cos function of cos(60). To figure this out i did the ArcSin and ArcCos of the values in the #define.

One way of thinking about sin and cos that helped me is that when you multiply a number by a decimal (like 0.866) you are taking 86.6% of the number. So when you take an x value and multiply it by cos and a y value and multiply it by sin, the x and/or y value can go up/down slightly which is how you can make a circle using sin and cos. (This explanation might not work for all but worked for my understanding).

As for efficiency of your algorithm, I am unsure since I didn't run your code but you could take a look at [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/koch-curve-koch-snowflake/). It contains an algorithm (in Python) but can be transposed to C++.